# How can I install GreenAsia Inc. 2.4G RX driver on manjaro manually?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, keyboard, manjaro

I have manjaro as my operating system and my wireless keyboard is not working with usb or bluetooth. the bluetooth way, it types after seconds i pressed any button. I found this page https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0e8f-00a7 but I dont know how to download or anything.

Comment: You don't download or install anything, it's been working with the kernel for years. If it is not working properly, then try it on a different system. Try running `xev` and see what king of keyboard response you get.

Comment: I tried it on Ubuntu and windows and none of them works. It only works on android phones via bluetooth. And trying `xev` it produces nothing.

Comment: That sounds like it has not been paired properly with either Windows or Linux.